Unit sphere isomorphism with SO(3)/SO(2)
In group theory we have the following theorem:
$$\textbf{Th: } \text{ Let $M$ be a homogeneus space of the group $G$ (Has only one orbit under G-action) and $p_0\in M$ be fixed}\\ \text{Let also $H:= G_{p_0}$ be thr stabilizer of $p_0$. Then there exists a unique isomorphism $F$ such that: }\\ F: G/H \rightarrow M \\ F(eH)=p_0\\ \text{Where $G/H$ is the set of cosets of the action of $H$ on $G$ .And this mapping is given by the expression:} \\ F(gH)=g\cdot p_0$$
Let's now look at a concrete example which utilizes that theorem.
$$\textbf{Ex:}\text{ Let's look at the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ denoted by $\mathbb{S}^2$}. \text{$\mathbb{S}^2$ is homogeneus space of the group SO$(3)$}. \\ \text{The stabilizer of the north pole  is the group SO(2) of rotation around the axis of the pole. So by the theorem:}\\
\mathbb{S}^2\approx \text{SO}(3)/\text{SO}(2)   $$
What I'm a little confused about and would appreciate some intuition is the following. To describe the unit sphere we need two degrees of freedom/ two angles - the azimuth and altitude. However Doesn't the set of cosets SO(3)/SO(2) require only one since we only need to rotate along the altitude to reach all possible cosets? If yes, how is that an isomorphism? Maybe my intuition of vizualizin the rotation is flawed because I imagine rotating the north pole somehow and then applying all possible azimuthal rotations and that is a certain coset (So we would need moving the north pole only along the lattitude).

Does this help you? The crux is that a rotation in $SO(3)$ actually requires three parameters, not 2. One axis and one angle specifies two rotations, so you need another parameter to fix a single rotation. $SO(2)$ requires one, so the quotient has 2 degrees of freesom.

The "theorem" that you state in the beginning is not really a theorem, as it lacks precision we require in math: It does not state what category of groups and group actions one is working with and what notion of an isomorphism one is using. In some categories (for instance, set theory and group actions on sets, or proper Lie group actions on smooth manifolds) this "theorem" is true and in some categories (e.g. topological spaces and continuous group actions) this "theorem" is false.

"[...] we only need to rotate along the altitude to reach all possible cosets? [...] I imagine rotating the north pole somehow and then applying all possible azimuthal rotations and that is a certain coset (So we would need moving the north pole only along the lattitude)"  I am having trouble understanding what you're describing here.

@HackR  It takes 2 parameters to specify an axis.

My guess is that the confusion in the question is between describing arbitrary points on the sphere (which takes 2 parameters) and describing points reachable from a specified point by rotations in the stabilizer of the north pole, i.e., points at  the same latitude (which takes 1 parameter, the longitude).

Your picture for $\text{SO}(3)$ does include $3$ parameters (see there are 3 arrows), so this is all consistent.
